# How to model an instance of a typescript interface in UML

Tags: angular, typescript, uml

I am designing a class diagram for a Angular application. Angular apps are written in TypeScript.

In TypeSCript it is possible to have an instance of an interface. For example an interface exists called cube:

```
interface ICube {
  sideLength: number
}
```

In the class Shapes this interface is used to define the type of an attribute (the class does not implement it) called myCube (as myCube is not a class it would make no sense to model it as such even know this is what implements the interface).

```
class Shape {
  myCube: ICube
}
```

I would think of this as a dependency the class has on the ICube interface but I have no idea how I would model a dependency in a design class diagram. Is there any official way of modelling this in UML?

Comment: He didn't ask for a UML modeling program.

Comment: this may be of interest - http://www.agilemodeling.com/style/classDiagram.htm#Interfaces

Comment: Dunno typescript, so what actually does `myCube: ICube` mean? If it were a variable declaration it would be a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a class C has a property P of type T, then class C automatically depends on type T. So, the most simple way of modeling your case is as follows:

[image: simple]

If you want to show the dependency explicitly using a relationship, you may draw a dashed arrow from the class to the interface, as follows:

[image: simple-with-dependency]

This dependency relationship is redundant, but allowed.

Side note: `number` is not a pre-defined UML type. You may either define `number` as a data type in UML, or use the pre-defined UML type `Real`.